# How to print Jasper Reports in a specified printer?

Tags: java, reporting-services, printing, jasper-reports

All I want, is to print a JasperReport without user selecting a printer. I searched for it but there is no good solution that works. This is the relevat part of my code:

```
//compile to .jasper
String report = JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(sourceFileName);

//fill the report
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameter, dataSource);

//print the report      
JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, true);
```

Instead of simple printReport i want to select a printer. is there any way to do this?

Comment: I can't be the only one struggling with this problem...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how it's supposed to be:

```
try {

    String report = JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(sourceFileName);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, para, ds);

    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PageFormat pageFormat = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
    printerJob.defaultPage(pageFormat);

    int selectedService = 0;

    AttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet(new PrinterName(printerNameShort, null));

    PrintService[] printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, attributeSet);

    try {
        printerJob.setPrintService(printService[selectedService]);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }
    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

    // these are deprecated
    exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, printService[selectedService]);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printService[selectedService].getAttributes());
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.exportReport();

} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Here is a Simple Solution for printing jasper report on specific printer**
Create One Method for Select printer & print report

```
private void PrintReportToPrinter(JasperPrint jp) throws JRException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    // printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4); //setting page size
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

    PrinterName printerName = new PrinterName("Microsoft XPS Document Writer", null); //gets printer 

    PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
    printServiceAttributeSet.add(printerName);

    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

then call this method like

```
/* your code*/
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ckotid", kid);

try {
    JasperDesign jsd = JRXmlLoader.load("report\\bill\\check_kot.jrxml");
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jsd);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters, con);
    //JasperPrintManager.printPage(jp, 0, false);
    //JasperPrint jp =reportEngine.fillReport() ;//it returns stream 
    PrintReportToPrinter(jp);//call method
```

Comment: I want to print on shared printer,How recognize printer name for shared printers. I use printer name "POS", It show as "POS on Server" in shared printer name.

Comment: you need to find printer name from printer settings and use that in code. like i have used "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". To avoid redundant code compilation you can store printer name in db and update their if printer name changes

Comment: Yes, Problem is it does not work for network shared printers. I have use name on printer setting, but it do not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

These codes are obsolete.
JRPrintServiceExporter.setParameter became deprecated in JasperReports 5.6. They introduced new interface Exporter and retrofitted all exporters to have ExporterInput, ReportExportConfiguration, ExporterConfiguration,ExporterOutput. See below link

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/Exporter.html

This means that instead of setParameter, you need to create configuration:

```
private void PrintReportToPrinter(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws JRException {

//Get the printers names
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

//Lets set the printer name based on the registered printers driver name (you can see the printer names in the services variable at debugging) 
String selectedPrinter = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";   
// String selectedPrinter = "\\\\S-BPPRINT\\HP Color LaserJet 4700"; // examlpe to network shared printer

System.out.println("Number of print services: " + services.length);
PrintService selectedService = null;

//Set the printing settings
PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));
if (jasperPrint.getOrientationValue() == net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.OrientationEnum.LANDSCAPE) { 
  printRequestAttributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE); 
} else { 
  printRequestAttributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT); 
} 
PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName(selectedPrinter, null));

JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);
configuration.setPrintServiceAttributeSet(printServiceAttributeSet);
configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(false);

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

//Iterate through available printer, and once matched with our <selectedPrinter>, go ahead and print!
if(services != null && services.length != 0){
  for(PrintService service : services){
      String existingPrinter = service.getName();
      if(existingPrinter.equals(selectedPrinter))
      {
          selectedService = service;
          break;
      }
  }
}
if(selectedService != null)
{   
  try{
      //Lets the printer do its magic!
      exporter.exportReport();
  }catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("JasperReport Error: "+e.getMessage());
  }
}else{
  System.out.println("JasperReport Error: Printer not found!");
}}
```

You can print by this code to a network shared printer too.

Answer (score 2):

Just Use this .no need to more code it handle jasper

```
JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
```

u use true it will show window

I tested it epson TM T82
It worked.

Comment: POS is used at shops etc so how they will choose printer every-time in window

Comment: no need to select printer while application running.you have set to Epson printer as default printer in computer

Comment: If they have two printers installed one for their personal use and one for customers (POS) then ? if they have hotel billing system: one printer on reception and one in kitchen then.?   JUST think out of box man if they have two printers then what.their daily prints will be sent to POS if you set it as default