# font not clear in jasper print in dot matrix printer with windows 7

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports

I'm developing a project using java and it allows user to print an invoice through the software. I used jasper report to generate the report and used the code given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028896/how-to-print-jasper-reports-in-a-specified-printer)solution and with my laptop which i use for development the print out was correct and printed properly (printer was EPSON LX-300+II  and OS is Windows 8.1).
But when i used complied jar file in client computer (Desktop with windows 7 and same printer) print out is not correct. The text are unreadable and and they are stick each other as shown below.[image: Error print]

Both computers have properly installed the printer driver and only different is OS version.

What I have tried,

1. Change font to Arial - but the problem is same
2. print through jasper viewer - same
3. exported report to PDF and word document and printed - this was OK but for the requirement I need printout through java
4. Use .jrxml file and .jasper file - but problem is same

All the problems are in windows 7 PC and in Windows 8 laptop printout was Correct.
What is the problem here and can anyone help for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this problem also occur if you print something with a non-Java program, like MS Word, or, for that matter, NotePad (if you don't have Word on that machine) ?

Comment: Check the driver settings for downloading fonts, and for font replacing.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt no, i tried using ms word with different type of fonts and they are printing correctly

Comment: Looks like a driver issue

Comment: @AlexK but MS word and other docs print correctly

Comment: Did you try to print with Java code the pdf file, for example?

Comment: @AlexK yes and i listed it in 'what i have done' and the printout is fine and clear

Comment: `exported report to PDF and word document and printed - this was OK but for the requirement I need printout through java`, `Did you try to print with Java code the pdf file, for example? - yes and i listed it in 'what i have done' and the printout is fine and clear` - I don't understand you. Did you print *pdf* with ***Java code***? This attempt was success, right? If yes, looks like the problem in code for printing report

Comment: @AlexK, I printed a jasper exported PDF file through JAVA using `Desktop` command in java and printout was clear. but here i cannot stop paper ejecting after print. To over come this used `ignore pagination` in jasper report and use java code to print. if there is a problem in code why printouts are clear when taken through laptop with win 8.1 and all the unclear outputs came from win 7 OS desktop PC

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your current JRE version. I had this problem and I solved it updating my JRE version. You may need check if you are running a 32bits JRE in a 64bits computer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dotmatrix printer does not understand the font you are using in your code. I had the same problem with windows 7 64 bit. Solution: download any dotmatrix (example 'Doctrice') font for windows. Then copy the font to windows "Fonts" folder. Then change your font in your code/declaration:

```
 Font fo = new Font("Doctrice",Font.PLAIN,20);
```

All that is left is adjust your dotmatrix printer preferences' quality. Your print-out  is now going to be a clear quality. Thank you.